# OpenERP Server Error When Click New Module Install

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I just now installed Odoo and it shown local modules with install button. I clicked install but no module is installed and always displayed with following error message.

I searched for answers with query "odoo arch mes_type" odoo module install error and many possible variations but not going anywhere.

In one thread it was told to upgrade with `sudo apt-get install python-passlib` but that didn't change anything.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 500, in _handle_exception
    # We need then to manage http sessions manually.
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 517, in dispatch
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 283, in _call_function
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 280, in checked_call
    # Backward for 7.0
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 733, in __call__
    # but we only store controllers directly inheriting from Controller
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 376, in response_wrap
    routing = kw.copy()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 975, in call_button
    def call_button(self, model, method, args, domain_id=None, context_id=None):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 963, in _call_kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 450, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 498, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 341, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 358, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 263, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 907, in convert_file
    convert_sql_import(cr, fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 997, in convert_xml_import
    xml_filename = xmlfile.name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 858, in parse
    for n in de.findall('./data'):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 771, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1060, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 322, in create
    context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 332, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 3979, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 464, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4170, in _create
    cr.execute('select parent_left from '+self._table+' where id=%s', (parent,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 1271, in _validate_fields
    errors.append(
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Field `mes_type` does not exist

Error context:
View `product.template.common.form`
[view_id: 332, xml_id: n/a, model: product.template, parent_id: n/a]" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/product/product_view.xml:46, near
<record id="product_template_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.common.form</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="mode">primary</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Product">
                    <field name="is_product_variant" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="product_variant_count" invisible="1"/>
                    <sheet>
                        <field name="id" invisible="True"/>
                        <div class="oe_right oe_button_box" style="width: 300px;" name="buttons">
                        </div>
                        <div class="oe_left" style="width: 500px;">
                            <field name="image_medium" widget="image" class="oe_avatar oe_left"/>
                            <div class="oe_title" style="width: 390px;">
                                <label class="oe_edit_only" for="name" string="Product Name"/>
                                <h1><field name="name" class="oe_inline"/></h1>
                                <div name="options" groups="base.group_user">
                                    <div>
                                        <field name="sale_ok"/>
                                        <label for="sale_ok"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <notebook>
                            <page string="Information">
                                <group colspan="4">
                                    <group>
                                        <field name="type"/>
                                        <field name="uom_id" on_change="onchange_uom(uom_id,uom_po_id)" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                                        <field name="list_price"/>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <field name="active"/>
                                    </group>
                                </group>
                                <group colspan="4">
                                    <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
                                </group>
                                <field name="description" placeholder="describe the product characteristics..."/>
                            </page>
                            <page string="Procurements" groups="base.group_user">
                                <group name="procurement">
                                    <group name="general">
                                        <field name="standard_price"/>
                                    </group>
                                    <group name="procurement_uom" groups="product.group_uom" string="Purchase">
                                        <field name="uom_po_id"/>
                                    </group>
                                </group>
                                <separator string="Suppliers"/>
                                <field name="seller_ids"/>
                                <separator string="Description for Suppliers"/>
                                <field name="description_purchase" placeholder="This note will be displayed on requests for quotation..."/>
                            </page>
                            <page string="Inventory">
                                <group name="inventory">
                                     <group name="status" string="Status">
                                        <field name="state"/>
                                        <field name="product_manager"/>
                                    </group>
                                    <group name="weight" string="Weights" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','=','service')]}">
                                        <field digits="(14, 3)" name="volume"/>
                                        <field digits="(14, 3)" name="weight"/>
                                        <field digits="(14, 3)" name="weight_net"/>
                                    </group>
                                </group>
                                <group name="packaging" string="Packaging" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','=','service')]}" groups="product.group_stock_packaging" colspan="4">
                                    <field name="packaging_ids" string="Configurations" context="{'tree_view_ref':'product.product_packaging_tree_view_product', 'form_view_ref': 'product.product_packaging_form_view_without_product'}"/>
                                </group>
                            </page>
                            <page string="Sales" attrs="{'invisible':[('sale_ok','=',False)]}" name="sales">
                                <group name="sale">
                                    <group name="sale_condition" string="Sale Conditions" colspan="3">
                                        <label for="warranty"/>
                                        <div>
                                            <field name="warranty" class="oe_inline"/> months
                                        </div>
                                    </group>
                                    <group groups="product.group_uos" string="Unit of Measure">
                                        <field name="uos_id"/>
                                        <field name="uos_coeff"/>
                                        <field name="mes_type"/>
                                    </group>
                                </group>
                                <group name="website_and_pos" col="2">
                                </group>
                                <separator string="Description for Quotations"/>
                                <field name="description_sale" placeholder="note to be displayed on quotations..."/>
                            </page>
                        </notebook>
                    </sheet>
                    <div class="oe_chatter">
                        <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                        <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: I also face the same issue, i solved with install new nightly version 8 from http://nightly.odoo.com/8.0/nightly/ and install it and also do `sudo apt-get install python-passlib` after than it's work fine.

Comment: I did as you said and got this as output
odoo is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

python-passlib is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

and then sudo service odoo restart and I logged out&in but no change.

Further, after log-in top header with black bar is present and messaging selected but just blank screen after that.

Only settings link works showing something.

Comment: ohh I see, than you may also try with github odoo branch and start server manually with proper addons path.

Comment: could you please guide me how to do that? finding that addon path is the confusing part...

Comment: Hey, I went to try different things like dropping table, checking path, give admin user technical rights and changed permissions of all files and folders to 755, then logged out and in... now it is showing sales module etc., but error for new module stays the same

Comment: hey today i wrote blogspot of odoo looked that might be helpful to you http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/

Comment: This is a new module or you are inheriting old/existing one?

Comment: @dirtyhandsphp this is fresh install and for all modules same error comes

Comment: Holy mother of god... it worked... odedra you're a genius... I still don't know how to select comment as answer... for anyone in future follow steps here http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-in-odoo.html